# Как убрать вот это расстояние перед <a> элементом

Tags: html, css

Как убрать вот это расстояние
[image: Расстояние подчёркнуто красным]

**HTML**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>MyFirstSite_copy_2_2</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
```

```
<header>

    <h1 class="headerTitle">Influencers</h1>

    <h4 class="headerLinks">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
        <a href="#">About</a>

    </h4>

</header>


<div class="about_person">

    <h2 class="personName">Egor Chulkov</h2>
    <p class="personQualification">German coach</p>

    <div class="person_info">

        <img class="person_img" src="Egor.png" alt="">    

        <div class="person_description">
            <h2>About Egor</h2>
            <p>Egor its a German language coach<br>
                Expirience:6 years
                Goethe certificat:C2
                Skype:1 hour
                Price:55$
            </p>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>

  <div class="about_person">

    <h2 class="personName">Michail Raduga</h2>
    <p class="personQualification">Faze state</p>

    <div class="person_info">

        <img class="person_img" src="Raduga.jpg" alt="">    
        
        <div class="person_description">
            <h2>About Michail</h2>
            <p>Michail its a faze state practic.He also have a book and teach people how to get in luquid dream<br>
                Expirience:22 years<br>
                Book:<a href="https://www.ozon.ru/product/faza-vzlamyvaya-illyuziyu-realnosti-raduga-mihail-227780671/">Faze</a><br>
                Price:12.6$
            </p>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    body {
    background-color:#171717;
    color:white;
}

header {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #303030;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    padding-right:30px;
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    box-shadow: 5px 3px 5px 2px #000000;
}


.headerTitle {
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: 40%;
}

a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: 16px;
}

a:hover {
    color: #808080;
}




.personName {
    padding-left: 4%;
    font-size: 32px;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 4%;
    margin-bottom: 0.5%;
}

.personQualification {
    padding-left: 4%;
    color:red;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.person_info {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    background-color: #303030;
    margin-left: 4%;
    margin-right: 4%;
    margin-top: 0.5%;
}

.about_person img {
    width:50%;
object-fit: contain;
max-height: 450px;

}

.person_description * {
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-top: 1%;
}

.person_description h2 {
    font-size: 28px;
}

.person_description p {
font-size: 18px;
}
```

Короче админы фиксите сами баги с ctrl+k - я нажал 5 минут потратил оно нормально не вставяет (как html так и css) проще на codepen залить

Comment: display: block и всё

Comment: @MonkeyMutant display: block чего?

Comment: `.person_description * ` а вот это зачем?

Comment: для ссылки дисплай блок

Comment: @MonkeyMutant получилось что-то типа такого https://prnt.sc/L7GoZm4Hp9iY изменял вот тут https://prnt.sc/XtwYRH3YANCd

Comment: @AlexeyTen это чтобы обратится ко всем элементам в контейнере div

Comment: вообще вам нужно вёрстку пересмотреть

Comment: где пересмотреть?

Comment: @MonkeyMutant где пересмотреть?

Comment: я имел ввиду переделать - не br а как положено парагарафами

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/LYJZxKv - что то типа этого

Comment: @MonkeyMutant окей переделаю

Comment: @nevazno_html_css_js_1 ну вы и обратились ко всем элементам. Включая `a`.

Comment: @AlexeyTen да я понял - спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.person_description * {
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-top: 1%;
}
```

для всех элементов внутри .person_description отступ слева 2%
margin-left: 2%;

Comment: Да спасибо вот этот код помог:
`.person_description h2,p {
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-top: 1%;
}`